# Facebook Connect button in Overlay (Drupal 7)

Tags: social-network

I've been helping a friend with a site, and recently run into a road block.

I've installed FB connect, set up an app, and it's working well from the home page.  However, he has an overlay installed for most of the forms and the Connect button doesn't display on the forms.

I've tried almost every variation that I can think of/find and nothing seems to be working.

Any advice?

I'm not able to post an image, but the sanbox site is at central-mining.com, just click on either of the login/registration links on the top menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of Facebook O auth module. It has a huge advantages over the module that you use. It will work fine with any overlay effect.